# how to change generated by ='' when sending reports

Tags: apex

I have an apex code that send a report in excel format as an attachment , it works really fine, i have created a button to test the code.

here is the code :

```
global class Sendemail {
webservice static String sendEmail(id idreport) {
ApexPages.PageReference report = null;
     user us = [select id , email from user where id =: id];
    report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/id?excel=printable+view');
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
attachment.setFileName('report.csv');
attachment.setBody(report.getContent());
attachment.setContentType('application/vnd.ms-excel');
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } );
message.setSubject('Report');
message.setPlainTextBody('The report is attached.');

message.setToAddresses( new String[] { us.email } );
Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message } );
    return 'ok';
    }
}
```

and this is the javascript code to execute this class:

```
sforce.apex.execute("Sendemail","sendEmail",{id:'005b0000002kiCl'});
```

Now, when i execute the code , i get the report in excel format but with the message inside the report

```
 genrated by :'xxxxxxxx'
```

where xxxxxxx is the administrator , i want to change the code in order to get instead of xxxxxxxx the name which corresponds to the id passed as a parameter to the javascript function that means if i put my id

```
sforce.apex.execute("Sendemail","sendEmail",{id:'MY ID'});
```

i should get genrated by :'Merabti Ibrahim' which is my name .

is that possible ?

Comment: Try calling `setSenderDisplayName` on your `SingleEmailMessage`.

Comment: Ok, i am gonna trying it , i will keep you informed

Comment: why do you need to pass the running user's ID into the webservice? doesn't the webservice already have access to `UserInfo.getUserId()`